# import javax.microedition in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to import the source code for an Android applet to eclipse, but got "The import javax.microedition cannot be resolved" error. I already installed oracle_java_me_sdk-3_2.exe, what else do I need to do? Is there any settings I need to change?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `jar` file which contains the package `javax.microedition` to your eclipse project classpath. If you are not sure which jar to use
check findjar

http://findjar.com/index.x?query=javax.microedition

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the required libraries (jar/bundle) to your project/classpath? If not, I believe you will have to do that manually, then you may need to attach the source to that libraries manually as well.